# HTML video does not play

Tags: javascript, html, video, createjs, preloadjs

I'm creating a video like this, based on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrteal/pen/BaaqJjQ):

```
export function createVideoFromBinary(src, mimeType = 'video/mp4') {
    let $video = $(`<video autoplay loop/>`);
    let $source = $(`<source type="${mimeType}"/>`);
    let blob = new Blob([src], {type: mimeType});
    let urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    let objUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
    $source.attr('src', objUrl);
    $video.append($source);
    return $video.get(0);
}
```

I'm preloading the video with PreloadJS:

```js
this.m_queue.loadFile({id: 'story1.womanOnBeach', src: 'res/img/story1/woman-on-beach.mp4', type: createjs.AbstractLoader.BINARY});
```

I'm using it like this:

```
let womanOnBeachVideo = PreloadedAssets.story1_womanOnBeach.cloneNode(true);
womanOnBeachVideo.autoplay = true;
this.container.appendChild(womanOnBeachVideo);
```

This video's first frame shows up, however the video doesn't play (the actual video I'm loading isn't a static image). Any insight on why?

### Update

The video plays if I put the `controls` attribute and play it manually, or if I programatically click it (`video.click()`). Is there a better way or is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers restrict the use of autoplay. Generally, a video will autoplay only if it's muted, its volume is 0, or when the user takes some action to initiate the video.

MDN goes into more depth with its [Autoplay guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide).